# Returning different outputs from Python + Numba

Tags: python, numba

I have a Python function that I am optimising for speed using Numba. However I need to have the function return a float64 (it will be called by a minimisation algorithm which requires a single float output). However I also need it to return information about the internal state once the optimisation is complete. This is represented by a tuple of 26 Numpy vectors.

Currently Numba only allows one type of output.

I have tried outputting the state to a file using an input flag thus avoiding a return type nut Numba does not like file I/O.

How else can I get access to the internal state and still use Numba ?

Comment: how about returning an array with 27 columns: 1 for float number (rest of rows zero-filled) and the other columns with the 26 numpy arrays content

Comment: I am not sure that the optimiser will allow that. It is expecting a single float.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to optimize for speed, you shouldn't involve the filesystem.

If the 26 vectors can be combined as a 2D Numpy array, you can pass it as another parameter to the function. Then you can modify its content inside the function.

If you get errors saying you can't modify the array, you will need to declare it read/write using

```
nb.types.Array(dtype=f8, ndim=2, layout="C", readonly=False)
```

This may also work with Numba UniTuple instead of a Numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using two functions, the objective function wraps the other.

fObj (x, *args) -> float64
returns a single float and is the one given to the optimiser

f(x, output_type, *args) -> float or np.array
returns different output depending on the output type flag. Hence I have code that looks like this

```
@njit 
def fObj(x, args*):    
    output_type = 1    
    output = f(x, output_type, *args)    
    return output

@njit 
def f(x, output_type, args*)

   ... code that calculates objective function ...

   if output_type == 1:
     return xopt
   else:
     return np.array(full_state)
```